# Google Spreadsheets redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, spreadsheet

Is it possible to redirect a URL in Google Spreadsheets script editor? 
I tried this, but it redirects before script is finished:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() 
      {$("#myiframe").load(window.location.replace('https://www.yahoo.es');});
</script>
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/a/ageinfo.es/spreadsheets/d/ID" width="760"
     height="700" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
   Loading...
</iframe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that google uses a protection like this to prevent the use of spreedsheet in an iframe

```
if ( window.top !== window.self )
{
    window.top.location=window.self.location;
}
```

What is this ?

```
$(function() 
{
   $("#myiframe").load(window.location.replace('https://www.yahoo.es');
})
```