# Using Google Sheets /copy url parameter in iframe usage case

Tags: iframe, google-sheets, copy, google-apps-for-education

I am designing an exercise in an e-learning application. I have a template Google Spreadsheet and can display the spreadsheet within the software as an iframe.

[image]

Document URL (it's just a sample table)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zmZ-oW8lC2Hus-G70O3CkhmGE5qqnoOGmSZMH6x526U/edit?usp=sharing

I learned about the `/copy` parameter that can be added to a url to generate a copy of that document so that the editing does not overwrite the original. Source: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/make-copy-trick-sharing-google-drive-documents/

Spreadsheet URL with copy parameter
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zmZ-oW8lC2Hus-G70O3CkhmGE5qqnoOGmSZMH6x526U/copy

[image: Copy Sheets]

However, when I run that url as the iframe's source, it returns an error:
[image]

I learned that it is not the issue with the iframe, having tried the url on the w3 schools iframe demo with the same result. Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

[image]

From this StackOverflow answer, I believe I understand that the iframe will not permit executing JavaScript within it and I expect that Javascript is being used to generate a copy.

Answer: [Google Spreadsheets redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681514/google-spreadsheets-redirect/23683201#23683201)

My question becomes, is there an alternative way for an end user (student) to generate a Google Sheets copy url and have that appear in an iframe in a homework lesson?

Desired Result:

This in the iframe (or equivalent):

[image: Copy Enabled]

and be able to edit that copy as their own document

[image: Desired Outcome in Application]

Comment: @player0 The sheet url is public, but it needs a (any) Google Account sign-in to view the spreadsheet.

Comment: I might be missing the point, but if all you want to do it insert a link so that the spreadsheet can be copied, then use plain html: `<a  href="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<<yourshredsheetcode>>/copy" target="_blank">Click here to copy the spreadsheet</a>`. But it IS correct that the person making the copy needs to have logged in (or be capable of logging in) with a valid Google account.

Comment: @Tedinoz Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, that would work and that is probably what we will use. For the question, I was trying to keep the spreadsheet within the interactive lesson (as an iframe or something else) so the user doesn't need to go outside of the lesson and into the browser and then need to switch back and forth between the browser spreadsheet and the lesson inside the learning application.